# Why does the UI not update for async functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a browser application where I want to change some text in the UI to say that the page is loading, then run a long process, and once the process is complete to say that the page is finished loading.

Using the code written below I can get this to work when I call `ProperlyUpdatesUIAsync`, where the text is changed while the long process is running, and then once the long process is complete, it changes again to indicate that it is done.

However, when I use the `DoesNotUpdateUIUntilEndAsync` method, the UI does not get updated until after the long process is finished, never showing the "loading" message.

Am I misunderstanding how `async`/`await` works with JavaScript?  Why does it work in the one case but not in the other?

```
async function ProperlyUpdatesUIAsync(numberOfImagesToLoad) {
    $("#PageStatusLabel").text("Loading..");

    await pauseExecutionAsync(2000);

    $("#PageStatusLabel").text("Loaded");
}

// this method doesn't do anything other than wait for the specified
// time before allowing execution to continue
async function pauseExecutionAsync(timeToWaitMilliseconds) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(null);
        }, timeToWaitMilliseconds);
    });
}


async function DoesNotUpdateUIUntilEndAsync(numberOfImagesToLoad) {
    $("#PageStatusLabel").text("Loading..");

    await runLongProcessAsync();

    $("#PageStatusLabel").text("Loaded");
}

async function runLongProcessAsync() {
    // there is a for loop in here that takes a really long time
}
```

**Edit:**
I experimented with a few things and this new refactor is giving me the desired result, but I do not like it.  I wrapped the long running loop in a setTimeout with a timeout setting of 10.  With a value of 10, the UI is updated before running the loop.  However, a value of 0 or even 1 does not allow the UI to update, and it continues to behave as if the timeout was not declared at all.  10 seems so arbitrary.  Can I really rely on that working in every scenario?  Shouldn't async/await defer execution until the UI is updated without my having to wrap everything in a timeout?

```
async function runLongProcessThatDoesNotBlockUIAsync() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
    // there is a for loop in here that takes a really long time
            resolve(null);
        }, 10);
    });
}
```

Comment: The question you want to ask is "How does JavaScript's event loop work?" there are a lot of very good blog posts and videos that can explain that topic.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ is a very good talk that explains the subject quite well.

Comment: As a sanity check you can `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#PageStatusLabel'))` in the beginning of `DoesNotUpdateUIUntilEndAsync` to make sure an element with that ID definitely exists on the page. It looks like you're using jQuery, which won't error if the element is missing.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED

The code in runLongProcessAsync() never yeilds/surrenders the thread for updates to take place.

try: -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

var keep;

async function DoesNotUpdateUIUntilEndAsync(numberOfImagesToLoad) {
    document.getElementById("PageStatusLabel").innerHTML="Loading..";
    p = new Promise((resolve) => {keep = resolve})           
    setTimeout(theRest,0); //let the Loading message appear
    return p;
}

async function theRest(){
    await runLongProcessAsync(); // Your await here is useless!

    document.getElementById("PageStatusLabel").innerHTML="Loaded";
    keep();
}
async function runLongProcessAsync() {
    // there is a for loop in here that takes a really long time
    for (var x=1; x<1000000000;x++){b=x^2}
}
</script>
<body onload="DoesNotUpdateUIUntilEndAsync(5)">

<p>Test</p>


<p id="PageStatusLabel"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what you are attempting but my guess is you want Web Worker to give you another thread. Either that or you don't understand that "await" just gets rid of the need for callbacks. If your code is purely synchronous simply labelling "async" does nothing.

Comment: what is the syntax with "Promise(;)"?  If I have the semicolon in (), then I get a parsing error, but if I change it to "Promise();", then execution stops at that line and never continues.

Comment: Sorry it was more pseudo code than code but you get the idea right? Your runLongProcessAsync() is Async in name only. Can you show me the actual code? If you were loading images with Ajax then I am wrong but I suspect you POC code is synchronously hogging the main thread preventing UI updates.

Comment: The long running process definitely does hog the thread, which blocks the UI.  I expect the UI to be blocked once it gets into that method, but because that method is marked async, I expect the code that came before the await to be given a chance to render before getting into that long blocking process.  Have a look at the edit I made to my original post.  I found that if I wait 10 ms before starting up the blocking code that the UI does render, but if I only wait for 1 ms that it does not.  This seems to be too arbitrary to count on in production, though.